# Finding unused pages in Classic ASp

Tags: asp-classic

Just got a huge (multi-hundred page) Classic ASP site. Is there an easy - or relatively easy - way to find out which pages aren't referenced by others? I've isolated any that run standalone.

Comment: Do you have cygwin installed and what is your grep knowledge like?  Did you use IIS logs to find the ones in use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in files that are included I would use grep and concentrate on the phrase `<!--#include` and cross reference this with active ASP pages in the ones you've identified and the IIS logs.  I wouldn't remove them for a few weeks but add extra code to track if they have loaded via the event log or similar, ensuring that you don't delete any you shouldn't.  Ones that don't get tracked you know you are safe to move/delete etc...

Comment: Just remembered that I haven't catered for the instances where Server.Execute is used, so I would grep for that too.